# How do I make a CMakeLists with only one cpp file and two .h files?

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-format

I have a file called proj10.cpp and two different .h files which are in a include folder and the .cpp file is in the src folder. I have no idea how to make the CMake file since the other ones ive done have had multiple .cpp files.

Comment: What have you tried?  Why can't you adapt your other `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: It should not be much different. Please edit your question and add your `CMakeLists.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the problem is, but anyway, you could try this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.7)
project (proj10)

add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} src/proj10.c)
target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC include)
```

for the next time, it would easier for us, if you show us what you've coded so far.